# How to insert data in a dropdown list

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu

We managed to get the drop down list menu however, we are having difficulties getting the data from sql. So far, this is what we got.

```
    <select>
    <option id="">--Select jobscope--</option>

<?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("host","user","password","database");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $getIT = mysqli_query("SELECT job_title FROM `job_details`");
        while($viewIT = mysqli_fetch_array($getIT)) {
        }

        ?>
        <option id="<?php echo $viewIT['job_title']?>"<?php echo $viewIT['job_title']?></option>

 </select>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having with this?

Comment: the data from database is not showing in our drop down menu list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't be like this ? with  tag inside WHILE LOOP

```
   while($viewIT = mysql_fetch_array($getIT)) {
       <option id="<?php echo $viewIT['job_title']?>"<?php echo $viewIT['job_title']?></option>
    }
```

Comment: I think this is the right track, but I do believe you would need to close and open the code tag for this to work as expected. (?>)

Comment: yupp!! Just my hint. am not from PHP :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM test_groups_tb WHERE user_id='$userid'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $dd .= "<option value='{$row['group_id']}'>{$row['group_name']}</option>";
}
```

Comment: i still can't do it.. do you mind helping me? i edit the codes again... :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not from php background. Try this.

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT job_title FROM job_details";
$result = $mysqli->query( $query );

echo '<select id="domain_account" name="domain_account" class="txtBox">';
echo '<option value="">-select-</option>';
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['job_title']; ?>"><?php echo $row['job_title']; ?></option>
<?php    
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use **PDO** or **MYSQLi** . **MYSQL*** is depriciated

U need to use that `<option id="<?php echo $viewIT['job_title']?>"<?php echo $viewIT['job_title']?></option>` line b/w while loop

```
$getIT = mysql_query("SELECT job_title FROM `job_details`");
while($viewIT = mysql_fetch_array($getIT)) {?>

<option id="<?php echo $viewIT['job_title']?>"<?php echo $viewIT['job_title']?></option>        
<?hp }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<option value="">--select--</option>

<?php 

while($rec = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

?>

<option value="<?=$rec['job_title']?>"><?=$rec['job_title']?></option>


<?php }

}?>

</select>
```